# Display all matching values from given list in comma separated

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets like this

```
ID | Name
-------------
1  | Shirt
2  | Shorts
3  | Pants
4  | Skirts

Product | Category ID
------------------------
PC001   | 1,2,3
PC002   | 1,3
PC003   | 1,4
PC004   | 4
```

I want to get result like below

```
Product | Category ID
------------------------
PC001   | Shirt,Shorts,Pants
PC002   | Shirt,Pants
PC003   | Shirt,Skirts
PC004   | Skirts
```

What is the formula to achieve that result? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `1,2,3` is in B2 try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,1,"Shirt"),2,"Shorts"),3,"Pants"),4,"Skirts")
```

in row 2 and copied down to suit.